# Method for loading a large SharePoint list (~65K records) into Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf, sharepoint

What would be decently performant approach to loading about 65,000 records from a SharePoint list into Silverlight? The list is composed of call data that the Silverlight app will roll up into a summarized chart. I tried with the Client OM and the fastest I could get the data was 2.5-3 minutes. And that was only getting a single column of the list.

I've also tried using the SharePoint WCF services, but when I try to add a service reference in Visual Studio 2010 I receive a vague Bad Request (400) error.

Would WCF be any faster than the Client OM or is there a feature in SharePoint for large lists that I could use? If WCF is faster, does anyone have any thoughts on why I would be getting the Bad Request error in VS2010?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need all 65K present when the app loads? I can give you a code sample for an paging strategy I use in Silverlight, if that would help.  We typically pull 200 rows per page, but you can throttle it differently... as long as paging is an option for you

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you create a server side web service for this data. With 65k+ records you are never going to be able to do that with decent performance.

Create a custom server side code that will read and process that data into a summarised list that can be rendered by the client.